# upload image into database using jersey rest api in postman?

Tags: hibernate, rest, api, java-8, jetty

I'm working on a project that needs to create rest API for uploading file/image into database.i have tried API which uploads the image into the local system. but I can't understand how to send data into the database. can anyone please help me to work with the API. Thanks in advance.

```
@POST
@Path("/Fileupload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response Upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {      

    return Response.ok(saveFile(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail)).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).build();
}

private String saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
   final String UPLOAD_FOLDER="D://UploadedFiles/";
    String filelocation = UPLOAD_FOLDER + fileDetail.getFileName();
    File file = new File(filelocation);

    try {
        createFolderIfNotExists(UPLOAD_FOLDER);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("could not create Folder").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).build();
    }
    try {

        Files.copy(uploadedInputStream,file.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return "file copied to "+filelocation;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "file did not copied";
    }
}
private void createFolderIfNotExists(String dirName)
        throws SecurityException {
    File theDir = new File(dirName);
    if (!theDir.exists()) {
        theDir.mkdir();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specified which database you are using, so just from bride point of view.

Image can be represented like this class:

```
@Entity
public class Image {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column( name = "mime_type" )
    private String mimeType;

    private String name;

    @Column( name = "data" )
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

where data is inputstream converted to byte[]

So you need just create new Image, fill it with data and store in to database like any other entity